# Spring WebMVC with Couchbase service - No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, couchbase

I am creating a simple Spring WebMVC app with thymeleaf and now I want to add a service which provides a connection to a `couchbase` server.

I tried to create the couchbase service on basis of the following tutorial [Couchbase with Spring-Boot and Spring Data](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/)

I have the following project structure:

```
src/main/java
    com.project
        config
            MvcWebApplicationInitializer
            MvcWebConfig
        controller
            IndexController
        model
            Area
            Building
            BuildingRepository
            BuildingService
            BuildingServiceImpl
```

When trying to autowire the service I get the exception that there is no bean named `couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping` which happens because my repository class extends `CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository` which throws the exception.

I get the following exception:

> [main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
>   Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher' [main] INFO
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate
>   - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode! [main] INFO
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate
>   - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode. [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate
>   - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 64ms. Found 1 repository interfaces. [main] WARN
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'buildingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'buildingRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'buildingRepository':
>   'buildingRepository' depends on missing bean
>   'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available [main]
>   ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'buildingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'buildingRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'buildingRepository':
>   'buildingRepository' depends on missing bean
>   'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
>
> As far as I understand it is not working because there is no bean
>   named `couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping`.

**My MvcWebConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.xplorg.controller")
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xplorg.model"})
public class MvcWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>xplorg</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Project</name>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.18.v20190429</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

****Update****

Adding a CouchbaseConfig class fixed the problem with the `couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping` but I get now another error, that there is now named bean `buildingRepository`. All classes are based on the tutorial [Couchbase with Spring-Boot and Spring Data](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/). Do I miss an annotations and therefore spring can not autowire the class?

**My repository class:**

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "building")
public interface BuildingRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Building, String> {

    List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId);

    Page<Building> findByCompanyIdAndNameLikeOrderByName(String companyId, String name, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and companyId = $1 and $2 within #{#n1ql.bucket}")
    Building findByCompanyAndAreaId(String companyId, String areaId);

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND ANY phone IN phoneNumbers SATISFIES phone = $1 END")
    List<Building> findByPhoneNumber(String telephoneNumber);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} and companyId = $1")
    Long countBuildings(String companyId);
}
```

My service class:

```
@Service
public class BuildingServiceImpl implements BuildingService {

    @Autowired
    private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyId(companyId);
    }

    public List<Building> findByCompanyIdAndNameLike(String companyId, String name, int page) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyIdAndNameLikeOrderByName(companyId, name, new PageRequest(page, 20))
                .getContent();
    }

    @Override
    public Building findByCompanyAndAreaId(String companyId, String areaId) {
        return buildingRepository.findByCompanyAndAreaId(companyId, areaId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Building> findByPhoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
        return buildingRepository.findByPhoneNumber(telephoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public Building findById(String buildingId) {
        return buildingRepository.findById(buildingId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Building save(Building building) {
        return buildingRepository.save(building);
    }

    @Override
    public Long countBuildings(String companyId) {
        return buildingRepository.countBuildings(companyId);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post your config class here ?

Comment: you havent declare the couchbase config ? server user pwd !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the config class couchebase server

Create a dedicate config class extending the [AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/couchbase.configuration.html) for your couhcebase as below ( server @ , user , pwd )

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xplorg.model"})
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList("your server ip (like localhost in local)");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "username";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return "passsword";
    }
}
```

also change `@ComponentScan("com.xplorg.controller")` to `@ComponentScan("com.xplorg")` in your project config so your repositories interface and service should be scanned

Comment: Thanks, it worked but now I get another exception. `No qualifying bean of type 'com.xplorg.model.BuildingRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.` I have a bean named BuildingRepository which is based on the tutorial [Couchbase with Spring-Boot and Spring Data](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/).

Comment: I think it comes from the @ComponentScan("com.xplorg.controller") ; in the mvc config change it to 
@ComponentScan("com.xplorg")

Comment: @Xplorg you're welocme I'm glad :)

Comment: Same issue with me too, have minimum couchbase configs but still while starting the application I am receiving this same issue, any answers to it ?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, can help ?